# Install static files for Python package

Tags: python

(forgive my poor English)

I'm writing setup.py for my Python app.

My app needs some static files (pictures). I should add these files to data_files array in setup.py, and files will be installed in "/usr/xxx" path on Linux.

Then how can my app access these files after installation? I don't think it's good idea to use abslote path (like /usr/share/xxx/xxx.png) in my app (it won't work on windows).

Comment: Why would you install them outside the path of the module?

Comment: How to install them inside the path of the module? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use [sys.prefix](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.prefix) instead of an absolute path:

```
filename = os.path.join(sys.prefix, "share", "xxx", "xxx.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

distribute/setuptools provides pkg_resources for this purpose (and will work with package installed by `python setup.py develop` or `pip install -e`).

api example::

```
    import pkg_resources 
    assert pkg_resources.resource_exists('fabric', 'README.txt')
    assert not pkg_resources.resource_isdir('fabric', 'README.txt')
    myfile_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('fabric', 'README.txt')
    myopen_file = pkg_resources.resource_stream('fabric', 'README.txt')
    myfile_str  = pkg_resources.resource_string('fabric', 'README.txt')
    contents_of_package = pkg_resources.resource_listdir('fabric', '')
```